# Characters $00, $11, etc., being erroneously replaced by preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

In a simple template parser anywhere `$00`, `$11`, etc. appears in the HTML it is being removed. I don't see what's in my pattern that is causing $10 to be stripped from the replacement.

What is strange is I've commented out nearly all of my code except the main preg_replace function that handles the tag. Seemingly there is no connection, but nearly everything else has been removed.

**Function** (not showing what's commented out):

```
public function output() {
    $output = file_get_contents($this->file);

    foreach ($this->values as $key => $value) {
        $dynamic = preg_quote($key);
        $pattern = '%\[@'.$dynamic.'.*?\]%';
        $output  = preg_replace($pattern, $value, $output);     

        if ($key == 'objective') {
            $objective = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML Excerpt**:

```
[if @objective]<div id="objective">[@objective]</div>[/if]
```

**Original value of 'objective'** (ie, `$value`):

> Obtain a position at XYZ Company where $words $100 !100 maximize my management skills, quality assurance, program development, and training experience.

**New value of 'objective'**:

> Obtain a position at XYZ Company where $words 0 !100 maximize my management skills, quality assurance, program development, and training experience.

Comment: `$xx` (where `x` is a digit) is used for backreferences in the replacement string of `preg_replace`. Perhaps it has something to do with that? Can't really tell without knowing what `$value` is.

Comment: @Madbreaks -- question is why is it happening, this replacement is not desired.

Comment: objective is a sample of $value where the issue occurs, you'll see I included both a before and after.

Comment: @jsuissa: This is how `preg_replace` works; it's a feature, not a bug. See [its documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Comment: I've been going through docs for a while now. I don't see what's in my pattern that is causing $10 to be stripped from replacement though...if you could point me to a specific reference within the docs, that would be great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Follow-up to comment on the question.)

`$xx` (where `x` is a digit) is used for backreferences in the replacement string of [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). If you want the replacement string to contain `$xx`, you have to escape it:

```
$value = preg_replace('/\\$\\d+/', '\\\\$0', $value);
```

This will replace `$xx` by `\$xx` in `$value`.

Comment: Thanks a ton. It worked like a charm. Going to read-up on back references now.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because in `preg_replace`, `$<number>` in the *replacement string* means "replace with the 'th capturing bracket within the pattern".

You'll have to tell PHP to ignore the '$' signs. I think you have to do this in a two-step process:

1. `str_replace("$","\\\$",$output);` -- this protects dollar signs by prepending a backslash
2. `preg_replace($pattern,$value,$output);`